# PySerial not writing data properly?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

Back story: I am working on a clinical research project where I am using using ML algorithms to operate servos that are to control the depth at which fiber optics are placed into the prostates of patients with prostate cancer for photodynamic therapy. I got my hands on an Arduino as my other I/O devices are being used for other projects.

I have to interface my Arduino with Python as I need to collect incoming spectroscopic data (from the patients' prostates) from some of the fibers.

Sending and receiving ASCII data works fine (itself), however attempting to send data from the Python front end to run the servo fails miserably. As an example (below), attempting to rotate the servo arm by 45 degrees results in the servo jolting in one direction, moving back and forth twice, and then parking at its resting position.

The Python front end:

```
import serial
import time
import sys

def create_serial_object():
    try:
        serial_object = serial.Serial(
        port='COM3',\
        baudrate=9600,\
        parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,\
        stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,\
        bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS,\
        timeout=1)
        print("Connected to: " + serial_object.portstr)
        time.sleep(2)
        return serial_object
    except Exception as exception:
        if exception == 'SerialException':
            serial_object.close()
            sys.exit(exception)


ser=create_serial_object()
time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':       
    try:
        data=45
        data=str(data).encode('ascii')
        print('We are sending: ',data)
        ser.write(data) # sends data to Serial.read();
        time.sleep(0.2);                  
        data=ser.readline().decode('ascii') # receives data from 
        Serial.println();
        print('We are receiving: ',data)

        ser.close()
    except:
        ser.close()
```

And the .ino back end:

```
#include <Servo.h>
Servo servo_1;
int incomingByte;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);     // opens serial port, sets data rate to 9600 bps
  servo_1.attach(9);
}

void loop() {

   if (Serial.available() > 0) {
   incomingByte = Serial.read(); // receives data from ser.write(data)

   delay(500);

   for (int i = 0; i <= incomingByte; i++){
     servo_1.write(i);
      delay(20);
   }

    Serial.write(incomingByte); // sends data to ser.readline();
 }
}
```

Running the .ino back end independently works fine. The servo arm rotates by 45 degrees and then returns to parking position rapidly as expected.

My guess is that incoming pyserial data is not being decoded properly by the .ino script. I have tried flushing the input and output buffers.

Comment: You are sending two bytes 52 and 53, but expecting byte 45. `ser.readline()` reads a line, but `Serial.write(incomingByte);` doesn't send a line.

Comment: Ahh yes. I knew I was doing something silly. Addition of an `int incomingByte = incomingByte - '0';` fixed my problem.